# Button not triggering function asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a form with only a file upload control and 2 gridviews, for each grid view we have an add button and a save button for the whole page:

So the first button for gridview1 works fine but the other 2 buttons are not even displaying the msgbox inside the function, I tried adding `CausesValidation=false` but that didn't changed anything.

What could be wrong?

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileup" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text=" + Add" ID="btnGrid2"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" ID="btnSave"/>
```

Comment: where is your `onclick` event???

Comment: I am using the id: Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

Comment: Are you assigning the event to the button at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" ID="btnSave"/>
```

To

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" ID="btnSave" onclick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

That is happening because you've copied whole event from another page and because of that actual event in aspx page is not generated.
Visual Studio gives facility of generating events automatically.
Just `Place a control in your page -> Go to Control's Properties -> Navigate to events. -> Find OnClick and duble click` there. It will generate your `buttonclick` event automatically in `aspx.vb` code behind file.

Or you can simply put a button in your design page and then by clicking on it will also generate buttonclick event automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Put the button on the page and then double click on the button will do the same thing.

Comment: Now i have in properties->events->Click = btnSave_Click but still the button is not triggered, plus when i doubleclick on the button in the design it takes me directly to the function it should triggers

Comment: Ohk so now check what you've changed before asking question here? Like in `CausesValidation` or `EnableEventValidation`. Did you've changed anything?

Comment: I've tried adding CausesValidation="false", and now i tried EnableEventValidation="False"

Comment: You actually don't need to add that. Take your code to it's initial stage. eliminate all changes and keep only event generation change in your code.

Comment: I think I am missing something here, nothing of the suggestions seems to work!! I tried deleting the button then adding a new one again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142152/discussion-between-chirag-and-guest012393).